# Python3: How to print an item in a string of a list in a data structure

Tags: python, string, list, variables, data-structures

Let's say that I have one list that has two other lists that contain one string,

```
foo = [['12345'],['abcdefg']]
```

How do I go about printing out "b" by using its index place value? I know that I could write every item in the list like,

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to use just one string.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, define precisely what exactly you want.

Comment: Did you try `foo[1][0][1]`?

Comment: Wait - you tried it, it worked, and now you're asking how to do it? I must be misunderstanding the chain of events.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I was responding to someone else with the comment "Essentially, yes." My bad for not mentioning their user name. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) are iterable objects and supports indexing,so you can use indexing to get a character from your string :

```
>>> foo[1][0][1]
'b'
```

Comment: Oh god the `[0]` suddenly makes so much sense +1

Comment: Not all iterable objects support indexing, so the fact that strings are iterable does not mean anything in this context.

Comment: @vaultah mmm yeah in that way it would be more precise! thanks for note that!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
print(foo[1][0][1])
```